# Analyze menu on Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know this sounds crazy, but I absolutely cannot find the Analyze menu. It is not on my menu bar. I have Visual Studio 2012 Express for desktop. Can someone please take a screenshot of where I can find it?

Here is my menu bar:
[image: Menu bar]

Also, is there any way I can reach the Performance Wizard without using the Analyze menu?

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be there? It would not surprise me at all if that's a feature reserved for the expensive paid versions and not included in the Express edition.

Comment: VS 2012/2013 Express does includes 'static code analysis' but that is done under the "Build" menu. Only VS 2013 Express for Windows (not "for Windows Desktop" or "for Web") includes the CPU profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using the [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) which is a full featured free version of Visual Studio (cannot be used by large corporations) than the express version.

Comment: The new VS 2013 Community Edition is absolutely the way to go if you fit the license requirements (basically an individual, student, or hobbyist). It's essentially the same as VS 2013 Pro including extensibility, the graphics debugger, CPU profiler, etc.